# What's the kernel of the codiagonal $k[x] \otimes_k k[x] \rightarrow k[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

maybe this question is really stupid, but I could not solve it after thinking for a while. Let $I$ be the kernel of the codiagonal map $$k[x] \otimes_k k[x] \rightarrow k[x]$$ given by $f(x) \otimes g(x) \mapsto f(x)g(x)$. If $k$ is a field (and, hence, an integral domain), then $I = 0$. However it's know in algebraic geometry that the sheaf of relative differentials $\Omega_{k[x]/k} = I/I^2$ is isomorphic to $k[ dx]$ as a $k[x]$-algebra! So, clearly there's a problem here!

What's wrong with my argument?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you say that the kernel is $0$? For example $$ 0 \neq x \otimes x^2 - x^2 \otimes x \in I$$

Comment: @Crostul You're right. Thank you! I was thinking something like it's zero on the generators, but this is wrong. I need to sleep before asking questions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is only showing that if an element of the form $f\otimes g$ lies in the kernel, then it must be zero. However the tensor product contains more elements. For example $x\otimes 1-1\otimes x$ is non-zero in the tensor product, but lies in the kernel.

Comment: More is true: the elements of this form generate $I$.